# Retrieve web page html content in c#

Tags: c#

I want to retrieve web page HTML content. I did. But in some web pages, when I get its content, data has shown as `{{data}}` (as shown in the page source of the web page). How can I retrieve HTML with full data?

I tried several methods but their result are same. (such as `WebClient().DownloadString` or `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` or `WebRequest` or `WebBrowser`)

Can you help me?

Comment: Many *"Single Page App"* frameworks (like Angular, Vue.js and React) simply send a token down where the page content goes in the HTML. Then complex Javascript code replaces the token with the content of the "page" in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks @Flydog57. What should I do?

Comment: You can host a browser component (preferably not based on IE), let it load, and then inspect the DOM. It won't be much fun

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Selenium?

```
new WebDriverManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://foo.bar");
var source = driver.PageSource;
```

Example derived from [here](https://www.qafox.com/selenium-c-sharp-retrieving-the-page-source/).

Comment: Thanks @Dan, but I can't find `ChromeDriver`. Already I install `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.26.14.313457.1` from NuGet but  `ChromeDriver` still is unknown!

Comment: Don't use that older package.  It seems to be an older, no longer supported version.  Try the latest of this package:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver/

Comment: FYI, this looks like the one you're currently trying to work with.  It hasn't been updated since 2015.  I would be really surprised if that one did work.  The other one, with version 87, was last updated 17 days ago.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebDriver.ChromeDriver/26.14.313457.1

Comment: Hey @Dan. `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver -Version 87.0.4280.8800` is not a dll file. It is an exe file. I use this but nothing happened! VS marks `ChromeDriver` with a red underline and it means `ChromeDriver` is not defined for VS.